# bigquery find if values appear in a certain order

Tags: google-bigquery

In bigquery I have

```
SELECT
  timestamp,
  JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_VALUE(labels.body), '$.app_status_code') AS code,
  JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_VALUE(labels.body), '$.app_id') AS app_id
  
FROM
`Default_bucket_dataset`.`_AllLogs`
WHERE
  JSON_VALUE(labels.body) IS NOT NULL 
  AND JSON_VALUE(labels.request_uri) LIKE '%appointments%' 
  AND JSON_VALUE(labels.request_method) LIKE '%POST%'
  AND JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_VALUE(labels.body), '$.app_id') is not null
  and timestamp >= TIMESTAMP('2024-01-24T14:57:33.266809+00:00') AND timestamp < TIMESTAMP('2024-01-24T15:57:33.266809+00:00')
```

This produces something like

```
1   2024-01-24 15:22:10.149791 UTC  "NEW"   "AAAAAA"
2   2024-01-24 15:22:39.638232 UTC  "NEW"   "BBBBBB"
3   2024-01-24 15:23:04.659341 UTC  "PENDING"   "AAAAAA"
4   2024-01-24 15:23:21.530601 UTC  "FINISHED" "AAAAAA"
2   2024-01-24 15:22:39.638232 UTC  "PENDING"   "BBBBBB"
2   2024-01-24 15:22:39.638232 UTC  "FINISHED"   "BBBBBB"
5   2024-01-24 16:23:21.530601 UTC  "NEW" "AAAAAA"
```

Is there a way to list only lines where NEW appears after FINISHED for a given app_id, so in the above example only AAAAAA would be output

I asked chatgtp which came up with

```
WITH LogsWithPreviousStatus AS (
  SELECT
    timestamp,
    JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_VALUE(labels.body), '$.app_status_code') AS app_code,
    JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_VALUE(labels.body), '$.app_id') AS app_id,
    LAG(JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_VALUE(labels.body), '$.app_status_code')) 
    OVER (PARTITION BY JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_VALUE(labels.body), '$.app_id') 
    ORDER BY timestamp) AS prev_status_code
  FROM
    `Default_bucket_dataset`.`_AllLogs`
  WHERE
    JSON_VALUE(labels.body) IS NOT NULL 
    AND JSON_VALUE(labels.request_uri) LIKE '%appointments%' 
    AND JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_VALUE(labels.body), '$.app_status_code') IN ('FINISHED', 'STARTED')
    AND JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_VALUE(labels.body), '$.app_id') IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT
  timestamp,
  app_code,
  app_id,
FROM
  LogsWithPreviousStatus
WHERE
  app_code = 'FINISHED' AND prev_status_code = 'STARTED'
)
```

This returned nothing

Comment: The high level intent returned by GenAI feels right ... at a logical level, you want to generate a query which returns all rows ordered by timestamp and from those, select only the rows where the "current" row has a state of "NEW" and the "previous" row has a state of "FINISHED".  The BigQuery LAG() function (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/navigation_functions#lag) will be your friend.  Have a bash with that ... if you get stuck, try posting a question with minimal SQL and trivial sample data abstracting as much as possible.